# $scope and $watch is not updating/working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

My ng-model is value not updating in controller bonded with $scope. There is no syntax error in my code that I can assure. Only one controller bonded with html. 
$watch is only running once when page is loaded.
Note that I have 220 around total watchers in my file and controller file is very big like 1500+ lines of code. To cross check I also bind one div with different controller and it is working as expected both $watch and $scope.

I have verified that my variable is not having duplicate name in entire project. I think angular gives no performance issue till 2000 watchers per page. But here that is not the case. Can someone please shed some light on this strange behavior. Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I am not posting code here as it was working fine when I started working on controller initially and on separate prototype also code works well. This behavior has been introduced recently with more and more code.

HTML file:

```
<div id="studentSearch" class="form-group__text row studentmargin">
<input id="search" type="text" class="studentSearch" tabindex="2"
       ng-keyup="$event.which === 13 && !disableSearch ? clickSearchButton(): ''"
       placeholder="Search by Name or Email"
       ng-model="searchString">
<label for="search">
    <button type="button" class="link" tabindex="3"
            ng-click="clickSearchButton()" ng-if="!searchResultFlag"
            ng-disabled="disableSearch">
        <span class="icon-search"></span>
    </button>
</label>
<button type="button" class="link" ng-click="clearStudentsSearch()"
        ng-if="searchResultFlag" tabindex="4">
    <span class="icon-close"></span>
</button>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('app.pages.course.details').controller("CourseDetailController", ['$scope', function($scope){

$scope.disableSearch = true;
$scope.$watch('searchString', function(oldValue, newValue){
    if(newValue.length >= 3) {
        $scope.disableSearch = false;
    }
});

$scope.clickSearchButton = function() {   /* Search logic */  } 
$scope.clearStudentsSearch = function() {
     $scope.searchString = ""; 
} }]);
```

So the logic is search icon will only get enabled once the searchString is greater than or equal to 3 letters. On clearing search button it gets cleared from UI and if we print the scope it has that value, Because of that on ENTER press, search work again.

Comment: Maybe should you post some code. Can't help you here.

Comment: I am not sure how to help without seeing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try using parent with the model ng-model="parent.name".